# What is the template used in this document (Babel 3.38 manual)?

Tags: templates, book-design

I am impressed by the elegance of the Babel manual downloadable from http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf. See below for an impression:

[image]

Does anybody know if this is a standard/open-source LaTeX template? If so, which one and where it could be fetched?

Comment: You can find the source of the `babel` documentation here: https://github.com/latex3/babel/blob/master/babel.dtx

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Why not to convert your comment into an answer? | More info on dtx files at https://fileinfo.com/extension/dtx

Comment: Thank you. A good looking document invites reading :-). But my main concern is the document is useful and, above all, understandable even for LaTeX newbies, so any suggestion in this regard is very welcome, too.